# Why isn't the file being read from being posted

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have code that is supposed to post a file to a php using js. It is not working. I have previously attempted to view the image that is being sent. This has not worked. Incase anyone wanted to view what the code does, this is a sample login: `username:john` & `password:1234`.If anyone could help me, thanks in advance.

This is the html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.13.0/firebase.js"></script>
        <script>
            // Initialize Firebase
            var config = {
                apiKey: "AIzaSyCg8CauUyZeBGffR_2yAv7hkb-pD9zuzrA",
                authDomain: "push-notifications-affa8.firebaseapp.com",
                databaseURL: "https://push-notifications-affa8.firebaseio.com",
                projectId: "push-notifications-affa8",
                storageBucket: "push-notifications-affa8.appspot.com",
                messagingSenderId: "1027448457059"
            };
            firebase.initializeApp(config);
        </script>
        <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
        <title>MegaLords</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
        <style>
            #fileToUpload {
                display:none;
            }
            #logout {
                all: initial;
                font-family: "Comic Sans MS", "Comic Sans", cursive;
                cursor: pointer;
            }
            #logout:hover{
                color: blue;
            }
        </style>
        <script src="script/main.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="test" class = "topnav">
            <a class=active>Home</a>
            <a href=news.php>News</a>
            <a href=contact.php>Contact</a>
            <a href=about.php>About</a>
            <a href=buy.php>Buy</a>
            <?php
                if(isset($_COOKIE['username'])){
                    echo    "<a href=game.php>Play</a>";
                    echo    "<button onclick=" . "document.getElementById('id04').style.display='block'" . ">Profile</button>";

                }else{
                    echo "<button onclick=" . "document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'" . ">Sign Up</button>";
                    echo "<button onclick=" . "document.getElementById('id02').style.display='block'" . "> Login</button>";
                }
                ?>
        </div>
        <div id="id01" class="modal" style = 'padding-top: 50px;'>
            <form id=signUpForm class="modal-content">
                <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
                <div class="container">
                    <h1>Sign Up</h1>
                    <p>Please fill in this form to create an account.</p>
                    <hr>
                    <p id ="errusra" class="err"></p>
                    <label><b>Username</b></label>
                    <input id="signUpUsername" type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" class = "profile" required>
                    <p id="erremaila" class="err"></p>
                    <label><b>Email</b></label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" id="signUpEmail" class = "profile" required>
                    <p id="errpswa" class="err"></p>
                    <label><b>Password</b></label>
                    <input id="signUpPassword"type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" class = "profile" required>
                    <p id="errrepswa" class="err"></p>
                    <label><b>Repeat Password</b></label>
                    <input type="password" placeholder="Repeat Password" id="passwordRepeat" class = "profile" required>
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" style="margin-bottom:15px"> Remember me
                    </label>
                    <p>By creating an account you agree to our <a href="#" style="color:dodgerblue">Terms & Privacy</a>.</p>
                    <div class="clearfix">
                        <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="cancelSignUpbtn">Cancel</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="signupbtn">Sign Up</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div id="id02" class="modal" style = "padding-top: 50px;">
            <form id="loginform"class="modal-content animate">      
                <div class="imgcontainer">
                    <span onclick="document.getElementById('id02').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
                    <img src="images/loginformimg.png" alt="Avatar" class="avatar">
                </div>
                <div class="container">
                    <p id="loginerr" class = 'err'></p> 
                    <label><b>Username</b></label>
                    <input id="loginUsername"type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" class="profile" required>
                    <label><b>Password</b></label>
                    <input id="loginPassword"type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" class = "profile" required>
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name = "cookies"> Remember me
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="container" style="background-color:#f1f1f1; overflow:auto;">
                    <button type="submit"style="background-color: #4CAF50;
                                                color: white;
                                                padding: 14px 20px;
                                                margin: 8px 0;
                                                border: none;
                                                cursor: pointer;
                                                width: 100%;">Login</button>
                    <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('id02').style.display='none'" class="cancelLoginbtn loginButton">Cancel</button>
                    <span class="psw">Forgot <a href="#">password?</a></span>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div id="id04" class="modal" style = "padding-top: 50px;">
            <form id="changeInfoForm"class = "modal-content animate">
                <div class="imgcontainer">
                    <?php
                        if(isset($_COOKIE['profilepic'])){
                            echo "<span onclick=" . '"document.getElementById(' . "'id04').style.display='none' " .  '" class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
                                <label for="fileToUpload">
                                    <img src="players/'. $_COOKIE['username']. '/' . $_COOKIE['profilepic'] . '" alt="Avatar" class="avatar" id="img">
                                </label>
                                <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">';
                        }else{
                            echo "<span onclick=" . '"document.getElementById(' . "'id04').style.display='none' " .  '" class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
                                <label for="fileToUpload">
                                    <img src="images/loginformimg.png" alt="Avatar" class="avatar">
                                </label>
                                <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">';
                        }
                    ?>
                </div>
                <div class="container">
                    <label>
                        <b>Username:</b> <input id=changeusername class="profile" name="username"value = <?php echo $_COOKIE['username'];?>>
                    </label>
                    <br>
                    <label>
                        <b>Email:</b> <input id=changeemail class="profile" name="email"value = <?php if(isset($_COOKIE['email'])){ echo $_COOKIE['email']; } ?>>
                    </label>
                    <br>
                    <label>
                        <b>New Password:</b> <input id="changerepassword"type="password" name="password"class="profile" >
                    </label>
                    <br>
                    <label>
                        <b>Current Password:</b> <input id=changepassword type="password" name="new-password"class="profile" required>
                    </label>
                    <br>
                </div>
                <div class="container" style="background-color:#f1f1f1; overflow:auto;">
                    <input type="submit"style="background-color: #4CAF50;
                                                color: white;
                                                padding: 14px 20px;
                                                margin: 8px 0;
                                                border: none;
                                                cursor: pointer;
                                                width: 100%;" value="Change Profile Info"name="submit">
                    <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('id04').style.display='none'" class="cancelLoginbtn loginButton">Cancel</button>
                    <span class="psw"><a id="logout"onclick="logout()">Logout</a></span>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <script src="profile.js"></script>
        <?php include 'selectimage.php'?>
        <h1>Welcome to MegaLords</h1>
        <p>MegaLords is a place where mortals can become gods, and fallen gods can become true gods once more. Becoming a god is a very difficult process, and cannot be explained. Contact me if you wish to become a god.
            <h4>Requirements</h4>
            <ul>
                <li>You must have beaten the game</li>
                <li>You must be a mortal or fallen god</li>
                <li>You must be weaker than a lower god</li>
                <li>You cannot be a mythical creature, but we are looking for mythical creatures</li>
            </ul>
            <h4>Instructions</h4>
            <ol>
                <li>Beat the game</li>
                <li>The Owner will immediately contact you, if not contact them</li>
                <li>The Owner will grant you goddhood</li>
            </ol>
        </p>
        <footer>
            <p>Posted by: Electrox</p>
            <p>Contact information: <a href="mailto:quimortemking@gmail.com">QuiMortemKing@gmail.com</a>.</p>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is the website

https://omegalords.ga/

This is the js

```
if(window.location.href == "http://megalords.000webhostapp.com"){
            window.location.href = "https://megalords.000webhostapp.com"
        }else {
            console.log(window.location.href)
        }
        // Get the modal
        var modalLogin = document.getElementById('id02');
        var modalSignUp = document.getElementById('id01');
        var modalProfile = document.getElementById('id04');
        var loginUsername = document.getElementById("loginUsername");
        var loginPassword = document.getElementById("loginPassword");
        var loginform = document.getElementById("loginform");
        var signUpEmail = document.getElementById("signUpEmail");
        var signUpUsername = document.getElementById("signUpUsername");
        var signUpPassword = document.getElementById("signUpPassword");
        var signUpRePassword = document.getElementById("passwordRepeat");
        var signUpForm = document.getElementById("signUpForm");
        var changeInfoUsername = document.getElementById("changeusername")
        var changeInfoEmail = document.getElementById("changeemail")
        var changeInfoPassword = document.getElementById("changepassword")
        var changeInfoRePassword = document.getElementById("changerepassword")
        var changeInfoForm = document.getElementById("changeInfoForm")
        // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
        window.onclick = function(event) {
            if (event.target == modalLogin) {
                modalLogin.style.display = "none";
            }else if (event.target == modalSignUp) {
                modalSignUp.style.dis4play = "none";
            }else if (event.target == modalProfile){
                modalProfile.style.display = "none";
            }
        }
        var style = document.createElement('style');
        var topnav = document.getElementsByClassName('topnav')[0];
        var percent = 1/topnav.childElementCount * 100;

        style.innerHTML += ".topnav a, button{float: left; color: #f2f2f2; text-align: center; padding: 14px 16px; text-decoration: none; font-size: 17px; BORDER: none; width: " + percent + "%; }"
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);
        var getEmail = function(){
            var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
                if(this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200){
                    if(this.responseText == "Please Refresh"){
                        location.reload();
                    }else {
                        return;
                    }
                }else if(this.status == 404 || this.readyState === 0 || this.status == 404 && this.readyState === 0){
                    document.body.innerHTML = "File Not Found"
                }
            }
            xhttp.open("GET", "getemail.php", true)
            xhttp.send()
        }
        var getProfilepic = function(){
            var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
                if(this.readyState == 4  && this.status == 200){
                    if(this.responseText == "Please Refresh"){
                        location.reload();
                    }else if(this.responseText == "Your Account is Broken. The Dev Has Been Notified"){
                        document.body.innerHTML += this.responseText
                    }else if(this.responseText == "No Profile Picture Found"){
                        var confirmation = confirm("Would You like to Set a Profile picture?");
                        if(confirmation === true){
                            modalProfile.style.display = "block"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            xhttp.open("GET", 'getprofileimage.php', true)
            xhttp.send()
        }
        var signUp = function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
                if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
                    if(this.responseText == "        Sign Up Complete"){
                        location.reload();
                    }else{
                        if(this.responseText == "No"){
                            document.getElementById("errusra").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                        }else{
                            switch(this.responseText){
                                case "        *That Username Is Taken":
                                    document.getElementById("errusra").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                                    document.getElementById("erremaila").innerHTML = "";
                                    document.getElementById("errpswa").innerHTML = "";
                                    document.getElementById("errrepswa").innerHTML = "";
                                    break;
                                case "        *You may only have letters and numbers as a username":
                                    document.getElementById("errusra").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                                    document.getElementById("erremaila").innerHTML = "";
                                    document.getElementById("errpswa").innerHTML = "";
                                    document.getElementById("errrepswa").innerHTML = "";
                                    break;
                                case "        *You must have between 2 and 8 characters as username":
                                    document.getElementById("errusra").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                                    document.getElementById("erremaila").innerHTML = "";
                                    document.getElementById("errpswa").innerHTML = "";
                                    document.getElementById("errrepswa").innerHTML = "";
                                    break;
                                case "        *Invalid email":
                                    document.getElementById("erremaila").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                                    document.getElementById("errusra").innerHTML = "";
                                    document.getElementById("errpswa").innerHTML = "";
                                    document.getElementById("errrepswa").innerHTML = "";
                                    break;
                                case "        *You must have at least one lowercase, uppercase, and a number as a password":
                                    document.getElementById("errpswa").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                                    document.getElementById("errusra").innerHTML = "";
                                    document.getElementById("erremaila").innerHTML = "";
                                    document.getElementById("errrepswa").innerHTML = "";
                                    break;
                                case "        *You may only have between 3 and 12 characters as password":
                                    document.getElementById("errpswa").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                                    document.getElementById("errusra").innerHTML = "";
                                    document.getElementById("erremaila").innerHTML = "";
                                    document.getElementById("errrepswa").innerHTML = "";
                                    break;
                                case "        *Passwords do not match":
                                    document.getElementById("errrepswa").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                                    document.getElementById("errusra").innerHTML = "";
                                    document.getElementById("erremaila").innerHTML = "";
                                    document.getElementById("errpswa").innerHTML = "";
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    document.body.innerHTML =this.responseText
                                    console.log(this.responseText)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            xhttp.open("GET",'checkregister.php?eml=' + signUpEmail.value + '&usrnm=' + signUpUsername.value + '&psw=' + signUpPassword.value + '&repsw='+ signUpRePassword.value,true);
            xhttp.send();
        }
        var login = function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
                    if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
                        if(this.responseText == "Login Successful!"){
                            location.reload();
                        }else{
                            modalLogin.style.display = "block";
                            console.log(this.responseText)
                            document.getElementById("loginerr").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                        }
                    }
                }
                xhttp.open("GET",'checklogin.php?usrnm=' + loginUsername.value + '&psw=' + loginPassword.value,true)
                xhttp.send();
        }
        var logout = function(){
            var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
                if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
                    location.reload();
                }
            }
            xhttp.open("GET",'logout.php', true);
            xhttp.send();
        }
        var changeInfo = function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            window.wormData = new FormData();
            var file = document.getElementById("fileToUpload").files[0];
            wormData.append('fileToUpload', file)
            wormData.append('username',changeInfoUsername.value);
            wormData.append('email',changeInfoEmail.value);
            wormData.append('password',changeInfoPassword.value);
            if(!(changeInfoRePassword.value == "")){
                wormData.append('new-password',changeInfoRePassword.value)
            }

            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
                if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
                    console.log(this.responseText)
                }
            }
            xhttp.open("POST","changeinfo.php",true);
            xhttp.send(wormData);
        }
        signUpForm.addEventListener('submit',signUp);
        loginform.addEventListener('submit',login);
        changeInfoForm.addEventListener('submit',changeInfo);
        getEmail();
        getProfilepic();
```

This is the php

```
<?php
    include 'templates/connect.php';
    if(isset($_POST['username'])){
        $username = $_POST['username'];
    }
    if(isset($_POST['email'])){
        $email = $_POST['email'];
    }
    if(isset($_POST['password'])){
        $password = $_POST['password'];
    }
    if(isset($_POST["new-password"])){
        $newpassword = $_POST["new-password"];
    }
    $currusername = $_COOKIE['username'];
    $query="SELECT * FROM `Users`
            WHERE `username` = '$currusername' AND `psw` = '$password';";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
    $id = $row[0];
    //echo $row[3];
    if(!$result || mysqli_num_rows($result) === 0){
        echo $username . $password;
    }else{
        if($row[1] === $username){
            if($row[3] === $email || $email == ""){
                if(isset($newpassword)){
                    $query="UPDATE `Users` SET `psw` = '$newpassword' WHERE `id` = '$id';";
                    echo $query;
                    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
                }else {
                    echo "Everything is the same";
                }
            }
        }else if(isset($email)){
            if(isset($newpassword)){
                $query="UPDATE `Users` SET `username` = '$username' WHERE id = '$id';
                        UPDATE `Users` SET `password` = '$newpassword' WHERE `id` = '$id';";
                rename('players/' . $row[1], 'players/' . $username);
                $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
            }
        }else if(isset($newpassword)){
            $query="UPDATE `Users` SET `username` = '$username' WHERE id = '$id';
                    UPDATE `Users` SET `email` = '$email' WHERE id = '$id';
                    UPDATE `Users` SET `password` = '$newpassword' WHERE `id` = '$id';";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
            rename('players/' . $row[1], 'players/' . $username);
        }else {
            echo "Everything is the same";
        }
    }
    foreach($_FILES as $data){
        echo $data[name];
    }
    if(isset($_FILES['fileToUpload'])){
        $target_dir = "players/". $_COOKIE['username'] . "/";
        $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
        $uploadOk = 1;
        $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
        // Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
        if(file_exists($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name']) || is_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'])) {
        $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
        if($check !== false) {
            echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
            $uploadOk = 1;
        } else {
            echo "File is not an image.";
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }
        // Check if file already exists
        if (file_exists($target_file)) {
            echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }
        // Check file size
        if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
            echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }
        // Allow certain file formats
        if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
            echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }
        // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
        if ($uploadOk == 0) {
            echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
            // if everything is ok, try to upload file
        } else {
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
                echo basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
                $query = "UPDATE `Users` SET `userimage` = '". $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"] . "' WHERE `username` = '$currusername'";
                unlink("players/$row[1]/$row[5]");
                $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
            } else {
                echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
            }
        }
    }
    }
?>
```

Comment: This is just "test code" right? You're not planning on leaving all that completely unsecure, just jam some user input into the database, code live for any length of time?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by this? I am under the impression that, as long as someone doesn't have the password to the db, they cannot enter the database?

Comment: Yes, this is test code.  I would still like to know what is wrong the code above, though.

Comment: Put this attribute in the form tag enctype="multipart/form-data".

Comment: This works. This is an answer not a comment by the way @nicolascolman

Comment: "I would still like to know what is wrong the code above, though." You mean other than the 2 glaringly obvious things I already mentioned, plain text passwords in the database and sql injection vulnerability? Did you even bother to research either of those?

Comment: Ofc I did. I'm doing so now. Why do you ask???

Comment: Because you made this statement? "I would still like to know what is wrong the code above, though." Not too good with language huh?

Comment: So are you saying that when i said "What is wrong with the code above", you didn't realize I meant the original question I asked?

Comment: How come anytime I ask or answer a question, I see you and it doesn't end well?

Comment: @electrox-qui-mortem I'm glad it was helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set the enctype attribute in your form, so that the server can read the file.

```
<form id="changeInfoForm" class = "modal-content animate" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```